# Firebase reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, invisible-recaptcha

Authenticate with Firebase with a Phone Number (JS) requires a mandatory [reCAPTCHA verifier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#set-up-the-recaptcha-verifier), it takes the ID of the container. For the ID of the container, I am generating a random one -

```js
firebase_recaptcha_container: "recaptcha-container",

firebase_recaptcha_reset: function() {
            

            if (typeof appVerifier != "undefined") {
                appVerifier.reset()
                appVerifier.clear()        
            } 
            
            let id = loadJS.firebase_recaptcha_container

            let newID = loadJS.randomString(10)
            $("#"+id).contents().remove()
            $("#"+id).prop("id", newID)
            loadJS.firebase_recaptcha_container = newID
            return newID

        }
```

then requesting for the RecaptchaVerifier and upon receiving I set this as a global variable window.appVerifier .

```js
firebase_recaptcha: function(name_r="default") {
            let promiseD = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(name_r, {
                'size': 'invisible',
                'callback': function(response) {
                    resolve(response)
                },
                'expired-callback': function(r) {
                    console.log("expired", r)
                },
                'isolated' : false
              });
              
            return promiseD
        },
         
    
_____________________
        
let container_recaptcha = $utils.firebase_recaptcha_reset()

window.appVerifier = await $utils.firebase_recaptcha(container_recaptcha)
```

It works totally fine for the very first time. But its a honest mistake for users not to use correct phone number. So for next time, I am doing the same thing again and getting error while generating the RecaptchaVerifier -

> reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Which sadly does not make sense as the new element is totally different and also clear, reset methods were called following the documentation. I am neither using any other reCaptcha on this page. Refreshing the page might be a possible solution but that I really hate. Any insight would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found the solution, looks like it was a stupid mistake!

Invoking firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier adds new recaptcha scripts, every time! Hence all needed to be done is, calling it once, it does the rest on its own.

Comment: I wonder why they have not mentioned it in the official document. thanks for updating

Answer (score 0):

This won't get fixed just by implementing recaptchaVerifier.clear() method.

In the callback where you are passing this appVerifier, you'll have to implement the above clear method and add that "recaptcha-container" using ref

The below would be the element in render method:

```
<div ref={recaptchaWrapperRef}>
        <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
      </div>
```

GenerateCaptcha function:

```
  const generateRecaptcha = () => {
appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
  "recaptcha-container",
  {
    size: "invisible",
  },
  authentication
);
```

Inside submit Callback:

```
if (appVerifier && recaptchaWrapperRef.current) {
        appVerifier.clear();
        recaptchaWrapperRef.current.innerHTML = `<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>`;
      }

      // Initialize new reCaptcha verifier
      generateRecaptcha();
```